# Android - visible and invisible buttons

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a button to become visible if there is one or more objects in an array, otherwise it will stay invisible.

I am used:

```
if (positionOverlay.geoPointsArrayList.size() <= 0){
    buttonClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    System.out.println("Clear button hidden");
}
else if (positionOverlay.geoPointsArrayList.size() >= 1) {
    buttonClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    System.out.println("Clear button visible");
}
```

The problem I am having is that it runs and on start up the array i am using is empty, so the button stays invisible, however when I add objects to the array it still stays invisible, suggesting that it doesnt run the code again.

I have placed the code above in the onCreate, could anyone tell me where i have gone wrong?

Comment: you have to make a callback this steps once you have populated your ArrayList. Else it is not possible for the system to go back to this code and execute the condition.

Comment: try  buttonClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 3):

When you alter your array of objects you'll need to run the code you have in `onCreate` - what you have now only ever checks on startup and isn't linked to the array being altered at all.

So in pseudocode if you have:

```
array.add("new item");
this.updateButton(); // This is where you have your button code.

array.remove("some other item");
this.updateButton(); // Check if you've gone below the limit again
```

Comment: self isn't java - did you mean this?

Comment: @Elemental yes, yes I did. Too much Objective C lately... Fixed.

Comment: Elemental: "So in pseudocode..." Not meant to be Java per-se.... @thegrinner Or maybe it is... In which case you are missing semicolons =)

Comment: @Tim It's kind of pseudo-Java :p But I think Elemental is right about that much, it's better that way to keep it close to Java, convention wise. Which is a really long way of saying I'm adding the semicolons.